Is there a way to combine two data tables where the new data that needs to be appended doesn't overlap and is appended above the body of the file?
Simplifying my csv files:
Old
Timestamp,Mined,Health,Reward
2024-03-16 07:33:41,13 hours ago,100%,6.45 BTC
2024-03-15 13:13:12,1 day ago,100%,6.63 BTC
2024-03-14 12:22:30,2 days ago,100%,6.65 BTC

New
Timestamp,Mined,Health,Reward
2024-03-17 15:35:41,3 weeks ago,100%,6.48 BTC
2024-03-17 01:56:43,4 weeks ago,100%,6.37 BTC
2024-03-16 20:43:50,4 weeks ago,99.58%,6.34 BTC
2024-03-16 07:33:41,4 weeks ago,100%,6.45 BTC
2024-03-15 13:13:12,4 weeks ago,100%,6.63 BTC

How would I add these together by the unique timestamps and how would I make it so it doesn't merge duplicating values? Right now they are bot in csv format.
I tried a variety of different functions but they would normally append at the bottom and not in order.

Why not simply sort after combining?

Welcome. If duplicates are a thing in your data, please include at least one in your [mre], as well as your code attempt that got you the closest to your desired output.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
